# Long-term daily climate anomalies

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to generate an Image Collection that corresponds to a long-term 20 year daily average and apply the historical 20 year average to future daily climate projections in the collection NEX-GDDP which runs from 1950-2100.
I have figured out how to apply the 20 year average on a yearly basis, but since I am hoping to apply this average from 2018-2099 in NEX-GDDP, I can't figure out how to iterate or loop this to apply it to  each corresponding day each year.

Here is my working code:

```js
var bandOfInterest = 'tasmin';
var NexFut = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP').map(table_bounds)
// Read in the NEX-GDDP HISTORICAL BASELINE

var nex = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP').map(table_bounds)
  .select(bandOfInterest).filterMetadata('scenario', 'equals', 'historical')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1980-01-01','2000-01-01'))//long term 20 year average
  // 
  ;

///////// Calculate average of all model outputs for each day /////////
var days = ee.List.sequence(1,365);

// Group by day, and then reduce within groups by day();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// day.
var byDay_20y = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      days.map(function (d) {
        return nex.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d,'day_of_year'))
                    .mean()
                    .set('day_of_year', d);
}));
//print(byDay_30y);
var day_image_20y = byDay_20y.toBands();
print(day_image_20y);


var NEX_2018 = NexFut.select('tasmin').map(table_bounds);

var startDate = ee.Date('2018-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2019-01-01');

// Define a base collection.
var pcp = NEX_2018.filterMetadata('scenario', 'equals', 'rcp45').filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Calc number of days between start and end dates.
var nDays = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate, 'day'));

// Enumerate a list of days.
var daysList = ee.List.sequence(0, nDays.subtract(1));

// Map over the list of days to make daily mean composites.
var NEXDayList = daysList.map(function(dayN){
  var t1 = startDate.advance(ee.Number(dayN), 'day');
  var t2 = t1.advance(1, 'day');
  var dailySum = pcp.filterDate(t1, t2).mean();
  var nBands = dailySum.bandNames().size();
  return dailySum
    
});

print(NEXDayList)
//var images_2019 = pcpDayList.toBands();
//print(images_2019);


// computed anomaly images in the new collection.
var anom = NEX_2018.map(function(image){
    return image.subtract(day_image_20y).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});
//print(anom.size());
```